# System.management reference in SQL CLR stored procedure

Tags: sql, assembly, clrstoredprocedure

I am trying to build an SQL CLR stored procedure that references an IBM WebSphere MQ dll. I'm having problems doing this on my work machine, so I decided to see if I could just get this to work on my home comp using localhost. I've made progress in getting a different error, however I'm not sure what this means:

Msg 10301, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Assembly 'amqmdnet' references assembly 'system.management, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.